# Error: package ‘ShotgunFunctionalizeR’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it

Tags: r

This is probably incredibly basic, but I'm at a complete loss. I am trying to install the package [ShotgunFunctionalizeR](http://shotgun.math.chalmers.se). Following the instructions on their website seems to install the package (once I updated the link).

```
> source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
Bioconductor version 3.5 (BiocInstaller 1.26.1), ?biocLite for help
> biocLite()
BioC_mirror: https://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor 3.5 (BiocInstaller 1.26.1), R 3.4.2 (2017-09-28).
> install.packages("ShotgunFunctionalizeR", contriburl="http://shotgun.math.chalmers.se")
trying URL 'http://shotgun.math.chalmers.se/ShotgunFunctionalizeR_1.2-9.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1131365 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/hm/1c09f98s1gbgnt8trbkstw2m0000gn/T//RtmpFUMl1r/downloaded_packages
```

However, when I try to load the package I get an error message:

```
> library(ShotgunFunctionalizeR)
Error: package ‘ShotgunFunctionalizeR’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
```

Does this mean I need to use an older version of R with this package? I have looked at every other StackOverflow question I could find on the topic, but have yet to find a solution that works for me. What am I missing here?? Many papers within the last few years have used this package so I know it should be possible to install. Any help would be much appreciated!!

I'm using R version 3.4.2 in RStudio Version 1.1.383 on a MacOS Sierra (version 10.12.6).

Comment: You could try downloading the [zip](http://shotgun.math.chalmers.se/)  and then install it via `install.packages("PATH", repos = NULL)`.

Comment: @JonGrub Thanks for your reply. When I download the zip and instal with `install.packages("PATH/ShotgunFunctionalizeR_1.2-9.tar", repos = NULL)` I get the error message `Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'`.

Comment: @JonGrub When I add `type = 'source'` it seems to download correctly `* installing *binary* package ‘ShotgunFunctionalizeR’ ...
* DONE (ShotgunFunctionalizeR)`, but again, when I try to load the package I get the error `Error: package ‘ShotgunFunctionalizeR’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it`.